# sending 'Response' when an operation is finished

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I am using `Express` to build a bunch of files based on the body of a `POST` request. Whenever an app receives a `POST Request`, it will call some long-running functions to generate the files:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    buildMyFiles(req.body);    // making files 
    res.send('got the post');
});
```

I do not want to send any response back until all of the files are created. How I can do that?

Comment: Depends on what `buildMyFiles` does but use some synchronization pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `buildMyFiles` to support an asynchronous callback event:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    buildMyFiles(req.body, function(err) {
        res.send('got the post');
    });
});

function buildMyFiles(body, callback) {
    /* 
    do lots of synchronous, long-running operations here
                    ^ emphasis

    if the build fails, define err (if the build succeeded, it'll be undefined)
    then execute the callback function 
    */

    callback(err);
}
```

If you wanted your builders to be asynchronous, you might consider using something like `async` to handle them in series. Since I don't know what your POST request looks like, I'll assuming `body.files` is an array and `buildFile` is anther asynchronous function you might write:

```
function buildMyFiles(body, callback) {
    async.each(body.files, function(file, callback) {
        buildFile(file, function(done) {
            callback()
        });
    }, function(err, results) {
       // async building is complete
       callback(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: huh, just saw your `synchronous` emphasis! is there anyway I can do this `asynchronously`?

Answer (score 0):

Send response after the return of multiple promise calls which are all being spawned

```js
    

app.post("/buildSomething", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    let klist = []; // Something from req.body
    
    let promisecalls = []
    for(let i=0;i<klist.length;i++)
    {
        let index = i+1;
        let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
           
            let str = klist[i].split(" ").join(",")
            var child = spawn('node', ['main.js',index,str], {shell: true});
            child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
            child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log('child-stdout-data: ' + data);
                });
            child.stdout.on('error', function(data) {
                    console.log('child-stdout-error: ' + data);
                    myReject(data);
                    return;
                });
            child.stdout.on('close', function(data) {
                    console.log('child-stdout-close: ' );
                    myResolve("OK");
                    return;
                });
        });
        promisecalls.push(myPromise);
    }

    Promise.all(promisecalls).then(()=>{
        console.log(' ✅ ✅ ✅ ✅ ✅ ✅ Done Promise.all!');
       // req.session.title = klist.join(" | ");
        res.redirect("/ProcessOver");
    });

});
```